# Java: How to delete a file

Tags: java

In the code below how come when it say that it has successfully deleted the file, but when I check the file is still there. How would I remove the file. Basically I'm trying the delete the first file that I made after I was done using it to create the second file.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File file = new File("Hello");
    try {
        file.createNewFile();
    } catch (Exception e) { }

    try {
        PrintWriter e = new PrintWriter(file);
        e.println("Hello hi");
        e.close();
    }catch (Exception e) {}

    File file2 = new File("Hello2");
    try {
        file2.createNewFile();
    } catch (Exception e) {}

    try {
        Scanner x = new Scanner(file);
        PrintWriter e = new PrintWriter(file);
        while (x.hasNextLine()) {
            System.out.println("Hello");}
             e.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {}
    try {
        file.delete();
        System.out.println("It was deleted");
    } catch (Exception e) { }
 }
}
```

Comment: [`File#delete`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#delete--) doesn't throw an `IOException`, it returns a `boolean` dictating success

Answer (score 2):

`file.delete()` doesn't throw an `IOException`, it returns a boolean check into `if` condition

```
 if(file.delete())
    {
        System.out.println("File deleted successfully");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Failed to delete the file");
    }
```